# How to decode the url in php where url is encoded with encodeURIComponent()

Tags: php, javascript, urlencode, urldecode

How to decode the url in php where url is encoded with encodeURIComponent()?

I have tried the urldecode() but then also..i don't the url which i have encoded...

I have to do this in php..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should use `rawurldecode()`.
See the [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php)

Answer (score 8):

you can use this function:

```
<?php
$string = 'http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com';
$output = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($string)); 
echo html_entity_decode($output,null,'UTF-8');
?>
```

output will be : `http://example.com`