# decode url with php

Tags: php, url

how can I decode following query string with php?

```
t=%B1Z%2B%26k%C9%BF%B1%3Fh%3Fd%3F%9F%2Fa%90%3Ft%C5%8B%A0%3F-%F9s%D5d+%E2sJ-B%9DE%D0T%FA%A4.%93%AF%A05%98d%F9%85%CC%22H%3Fd%F9%9D%C3%22hE%8B%C1%D65%3F%A8%3A%25%24&charset=ISO-8859-1
```

I've already tried urldecode but I get following output

t=±Z+&kÉ¿±?h?d?Ÿ/a?tÅ‹ ?-ùsÕd âsJ-BEÐTú¤.“¯ 5˜dù…Ì"H?dùÃ"hE‹ÁÖ5?¨:%$&charset=ISO-8859-1

I've tried many ways but couldn't decode it

thanks in advance

Comment: try: url_decode() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode the url in php where url is encoded with encodeURIComponent()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757911/how-to-decode-the-url-in-php-where-url-is-encoded-with-encodeuricomponent)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to "decode" and parse your string, as in the example snippet further down in this post.

Read more about the function in php.net's manual:

- [PHP: parse_str - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

---

```
$data = "t=%B1Z%2B%26k%C9%BF%B1%3Fh%3Fd%3F%9F%2Fa%90%3Ft%C5%8B%A0%3F-%F9s%D5d+%E2sJ-B%9DE%D0T%FA%A4.%93%AF%A05%98d%F9%85%CC%22H%3Fd%F9%9D%C3%22hE%8B%C1%D65%3F%A8%3A%25%24&charset=ISO-8859-1";

parse_str ($data, $out);
print_r   ($out);
```

---

```
Array
(
    [t] => ±Z+&kÉ¿±?h?d?/a?tÅ ?-ùsÕd âsJ-BEÐTú¤.¯ 5dùÌ\"H?dùÃ\"hEÁÖ5?¨:%$
    [charset] => ISO-8859-1
)
```

Comment: @qwera it might not be, but it's the data in it's raw form. Where does the data come from?

Comment: It contains Norwegian + English language

Comment: @qwera Where does it come from, where did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

Read about urlencode and urldecode [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
$output = urldecode($encoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)!

```
$decoded = urldecode(substr($queryString,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this one might help:

```
<?php
$variable = 'http%3A%2F%2Fsample.com';
$variable = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($variable)); 
$variable = html_entity_decode($variable,null,'UTF-8');
echo $variable;
?>
```

output will be : `http://sample.com`