# php urldecode not working correctly when receiving response from ajax in javascript

Tags: php, character-encoding, urlencode, urldecode

I have explained all the steps below and captured data at each stage.

I can't understand why urldecode is not working correctly in this case?

```
Original String:
  <p>​hello</p>

Javascript encodeURIComponent() of above string:
  %3Cp%3E%E2%80%8Bhello%3C%2Fp%3E

Sent via Ajax: 
  %3Cp%3E%E2%80%8Bhello%3C%2Fp%3E

PHP: Echo $_REQUEST['string'];
  %3Cp%3E%E2%80%8Bhello%3C%2Fp%3E

PHP: urldecode of above string
  â€‹hello
```

Comment: That isn't a URI that you are trying to encode.

Comment: Yes it is, test it manually on this form: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: have you tried the solution here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757911/how-to-decode-the-url-in-php-where-url-is-encoded-with-encodeuricomponent

Answer (score 0):

There's a special hidden character between `>` and `h`. You'll be able to see it if you view the string as html in a browser.