# Get Url Parameter

Tags: php

I am having a simple problem. I need to get the parameter value from url.

URL is like this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?someUrl=http://www.example.com/folder/index.htm#<id=18025>>newwnd=false
```

I need to get the value of `someUrl` in php.

What i tried:

```
$_GET['someUrl'];
```

Output I am getting is `http://www.example.com/folder/index.htm`

Output need to get :

```
http://www.example.com/folder/index.htm#<id=18025>>newwnd=false
```

**Note:** I can't separate the URL after # into new parameter.

I hope i am able to clear the question.

**EDIT**: As per the valuable feedback, i have encoded the string before sending into as a URL parameter.

I did encoding by javascript function `encodeURIComponent`
Now URL become like below:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?someUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%folder%2Ftallyhelp.htm%23%253Cid%3D18025%253E%253Enewwnd%3Dfalse
```

After decoding in php by `urldecode` function, i am getting the result `http://www.example.com/folder/index.htm#>newwnd=false`
'id' remove from the result.

Comment: try encoding the url before sending

Comment: first try to explode the URL with `#`, then get the value by merge the exploded values

Comment: Or you may use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) but I'll recommend what @Sharky said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that if your request to your page is this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?someUrl=http://www.example.com/folder/index.htm#<id=18025>>newwnd=false
```

then whatever is after the `#` is an anchor tag, that means whatever follows is not a parameter that you can `$_GET`, its just an anchor tag. so you need to encode that `#` (and some other strange characters that can cause more problems)

so if you manage to make your request to your page like this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?someUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Ffolder%2Findex.htm%23%3Cid%3D18025%3E%3Enewwnd%3Dfalse
```

then you will be able to use `$_GET['someUrl'];` to get the value you want because the `#` will be encoded (among other characters too)

so how to make your request like this? simply use `urlencode` to encode your `someUrl` parameter.

see how it works

```
echo urlencode('http://www.example.com/folder/index.htm#<id=18025>>newwnd=false');
```

so after encoding your links that pointing to that page will be like this

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?someUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Ffolder%2Findex.htm%23%3Cid%3D18025%3E%3Enewwnd%3Dfalse">my link</a>
```

as you can see the `#` will be encoded and that will stop it from messing with the request's url and you will be able to get this string via `$_GET['someUrl'];`

**UPDATE for OP's new edit:**

if you encoded with js's `encodeURIComponent` then use `rawurldecode()` in PHP. see [How to decode the url in php where url is encoded with encodeURIComponent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757911/how-to-decode-the-url-in-php-where-url-is-encoded-with-encodeuricomponent) which has another answer also that may help.

Comment: i can't encode the url in php so i did by using javascript function but after decoding the same with php function not getting the proper result.

Comment: @VishnuSharma hello see answer again